# Downtime while changing MPM and recompiling Apache (via WHM)

Tags: apache-httpd

We have our website hosted on a popular provider. On WHM panel there is an option to turn off MPM worker and turn on MPM event. I understand, Apache would recompile after such a change. Will there be any down time during this process?

Answer (score 1):

Such a change shouldn’t involve recompiling anything, only restarting the service with its new configuration. The downtime should be minimal.

If you particularly care about qualifying potential downtime ahead of time, I recommend having a test environment identical to your production environment, and verifying the change there.